# A4SWIFT on BizTalk: Generating a valid MT103; how to create the CHK and MAC fields?

Tags: biztalk, swift-mt, a4swift

We're working on using BizTalk generate a valid SWIFT message (initially MT 103) and dropping it onto an endpoint. However, we're struggling to generate a valid message.

As part of this, we think we need to clear up our thinking surrounding the SWIFT FIN MT 103 Trailer block fields, `CHK` and `MAC`.

**Firstly, is this BizTalk/A4SWIFT's responsibility, or should we generate these fields?**

Microsoft's documentation says:

> The actual FIN interface or the SWIFT network appends the trailers. If
>   a message contains a trailer when A4SWIFT receives the message,
>   A4SWIFT carries the trailer with the message. A4SWIFT does not raise
>   an error if a message does not contain a trailer when A4SWIFT receives
>   the message. As with headers, all of the trailer entries, including
>   the blocks themselves, are optional in A4SWIFT.
>
> [SWIFT Header and Trailer Schemas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee350710.aspx)

... but this seems to be talking about inward SWIFTs with the `{5:}` trailer and `CHK` and `MAC` fields.

**Secondly, if it is our concern, how do we generate the CHK and MAC?**

Even when we figure that out, there seems to be a location in the A4SWIFT MT 103 schema for the CHK ...

[image: The location of the CHK field in the A4SWIFT MT103 XSD]

... but not for the MAC which seems to be some form of authentication token.

Comment: You say you are struggling to generate a valid message.  Does that mean you are getting some errors from the target system?   What are the errors you are getting.   You are right that the documentation is a bit vague about generating the Trailer section.  This article http://coding.pstodulka.com/2015/01/10/anatomy-of-a-swift-message/ states that "SWIFT network can append an additional System trailer block 'S'. For example {S:{SAC:}{COP:P}}." Implying those aren't the senders responsibility

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the link. I think I've read every document on the entire internet about generating SWIFT messages. All the same candidates come up, but none ring entirely true.

To fill that claim in and answer your question, our current SWIFT system does append the MAC and CHK fields, so in replacing that, one would think we need to do the same. Also I think the S field is an Alliance thing, which we don't use? We're not sending SWIFT out to anyone yet, the output is just wrong to even think about sending it out.

Comment: I realise I haven't put the actual SWIFT message on this question (I don't think it's important to the spirit of the question), but I have a second question more directly related to the output of the process at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524723/a4swift-on-biztalk-generating-a-valid-mt103-how-to-understand-why-a-message-is?noredirect=1#comment76055970_44524723 which I notice you've already seen. Thanks for your help.