# A4SWIFT on BizTalk: Generating a valid MT103; How to understand why a message isn't being generated?

Tags: biztalk, swift-mt, a4swift

We're working on using BizTalk generate a valid SWIFT message (initially MT 103) and dropping it onto an endpoint. However, we're struggling to generate a valid message.

*(Similar, but different question, at [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524346/a4swift-on-biztalk-generating-a-valid-mt103-how-to-create-the-chk-and-mac-fiel). I broke the questions up because they are materially different.)*

Given a populated A4SWIFT MT103 schema (namespace: `http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/Solutions/FinancialServices/SWIFT/Categroy1/MT103`), we're passing that through the SWIFT Assembler on a Pipeline, out of which we get a "flat" SWIFT MT 103 message.

We get a SWIFT message like that below (obviously false):

```
{1:F01ABCDEFGXAXXX0000000000}{2:I103ABCDEFGHXXXXN}{3:{108:143136}
:20:ABCDEF123456
:23B:CRED
:32A:170607USD500,1
:33B:USD500,1
:50F:/0000000000
Bible Baggins
1 Bag End
Hobbiton
ME1
:53A:/00000000
ABCDEFGXXXX
:57A:ABCDEF
:59F:/00000000000000
CashYourJewelleryFast.com
:71A:OUR
-}
```

Notice that **Block 3 hasn't been terminated correctly** and that **Block 4 doesn't start correctly**.

I'm missing the characters: `}{4:`

Dijkgraaf asked for the original XML. This is shown below (anonymised as best as I can to match the example):

```
<ns1:SWIFT_CATEGORY1_MT103_Interchange 
    xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/Solutions/FinancialServices/SWIFT/Category1/MT103" 
    xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/Solutions/FinancialServices/SWIFT/BaseTypes" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/Solutions/FinancialServices/SWIFT/DataTypes">
    <SWIFTHeader>
        <BasicHeaderBlock>
            <ApplicationIdentifier>F</ApplicationIdentifier>
            <ServiceIdentifier>01</ServiceIdentifier>
            <LTAddress>ABCDEFGXAXXX</LTAddress>
            <SessionNumber>0000</SessionNumber>
            <SequenceNumber>000000</SequenceNumber>
        </BasicHeaderBlock>
        <ApplicationHeaderBlock_Input>
            <MessageType>103</MessageType>
            <DestinationAddress>ABCDEFGHXXXX</DestinationAddress>
            <MessagePriority>N</MessagePriority>
        </ApplicationHeaderBlock_Input>
        <UserHeaderBlock>
            <MessageUserReference_108>
                <Reference>143136</Reference>
            </MessageUserReference_108>
        </UserHeaderBlock>
    </SWIFTHeader>
    <SWIFT_CATEGORY1_MT103>
        <SendersReference_20>
            <Reference>ABCDEF123456</Reference>
        </SendersReference_20>
        <BankOperationCode_23B>
            <Type>CRED</Type>
        </BankOperationCode_23B>
        <ValueDateCurrencyInterbankSettledAmount_32A>
            <Date>170607</Date>
            <Currency>USD</Currency>
            <Amount>500,1</Amount>
        </ValueDateCurrencyInterbankSettledAmount_32A>
        <CurrencyInstructedAmount_33B>
            <Currency>USD</Currency>
            <Amount>500,1</Amount>
        </CurrencyInstructedAmount_33B>
        <OrderingCustomer_50F>
            <OrderingCustomerIdentification_1>
                <Account>0000000000</Account>
            </OrderingCustomerIdentification_1>
            <NameAndAddress>
                <Line1>
                    <nameAndAddressLineType_1>Bilbo Baggins</nameAndAddressLineType_1>
                </Line1>
                <Line2>
                    <nameAndAddressLineType_1>1 Bag End</nameAndAddressLineType_1>
                </Line2>
                <Line3>
                    <nameAndAddressLineType_1>Hobbiton</nameAndAddressLineType_1>
                </Line3>
                <Line4>
                    <nameAndAddressLineType_1>ME1</nameAndAddressLineType_1>
                </Line4>
            </NameAndAddress>
        </OrderingCustomer_50F>
        <SendersCorrespondent_53A>
            <PartyIdentifier>
                <Identifier>00000000</Identifier>
            </PartyIdentifier>
            <BankIdentifierCode>
                <BankCode>ABCD</BankCode>
                <CountryCode>EF</CountryCode>
                <AreaCode>GH</AreaCode>
                <BranchCode>XXX</BranchCode>
            </BankIdentifierCode>
        </SendersCorrespondent_53A>
        <AccountWithInstitution_57A>
            <BankIdentifierCode>
                <BankCode>ABCD</BankCode>
                <CountryCode>EF</CountryCode>
                <AreaCode>EF</AreaCode>
                <BranchCode>XXX</BranchCode>
            </BankIdentifierCode>
        </AccountWithInstitution_57A>
        <BeneficiaryCustomer_59F>
            <Account>
                <Account>00000000000000</Account>
                <NameAndAddress>
                    <Line1>
                        <nameAndAddressLineType_1>CashYourJewelleryFast.com</nameAndAddressLineType_1>
                    </Line1>
                </NameAndAddress>
            </Account>
        </BeneficiaryCustomer_59F>
        <DetailsOfCharges_71A>
            <Code>OUR</Code>
        </DetailsOfCharges_71A>
    </SWIFT_CATEGORY1_MT103>
</ns1:SWIFT_CATEGORY1_MT103_Interchange>
```

I've checked the generated MT 103 message with known valid MT 103 messages generated in other systems and I'm confidence the details are present and in the correct format.

I suspect BizTalk/A4SWIFT have a bit of a fit when something is wrong and generates a half-created message.

Is there something I am missing? Where can I find actual errors associated with this, as opposed to just the counts? I can generate `<UnparsedMessages />` and can route errors around based on the promoted properties but they don't contain any useful information.

Comment: Can you give us the XML message that is creating the Swift message?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I've added the A4SWIFT XML anonymised to the example as best as I can.